# Custom layout for website back-end with MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a website with a front-end dependent on the `_Layout` file in `MVC` for navigation but it is not applicable in the back-end so I would like to use a custom Layout file for this.

I have seen this used often.

```
Layout = ViewData["~/Views/Shared/_AdminShared.cshtml"];
```

It would be placed in the view, this, however did not work for me.

Are there any better alternatives? Why does this solution not work?

`_AdminShared.cshtml` just contains the default `_Layout` content found on a new `MVC` project (for now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use your custom layout by doing this without the ViewData:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "CustomLayout";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminShared.cshtml";
}
```

Make sure that the layout is really existing under the Shared folder.

You can also directly declare it in your Controller specific to your desired View:

```
return View("Index", "~/Views/Shared/_AdminShared.cshtml", Model);
```